# Raphaeljs javascript error

Tags: javascript, function, raphael

I want to draw a rectangle using raphael.js inside a function. What is wrong with my code?

JsFiddle [Code](http://jsfiddle.net/yka3y/)

```
window.onload = function(){
    var paper = Raphael(0,0,100,200);

    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    var a = 10;
    var b = 20;

    function drawRect(x,y,a,b){            
        paper.rect(x,y,a,b);
    }        
}​
```

Comment: you did not call the function `drawRect()`, everything else adds up just fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.onload = function(){
    var paper = Raphael(0,0,100,200);

    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    var a = 10;
    var b = 20;

    function drawRect(x,y,a,b){            
        paper.rect(x,y,a,b);
    }

    drawRect(x,y,a,b);  //Call the function that you just defined!!
}​
```